# "Mad Gadget" (de-serialisation) vulnerability Java example?

Tags: java, deserialization, apache-commons

Apache Commons states ([link to statement](https://blogs.apache.org/foundation/entry/apache_commons_statement_to_widespread)):

> By combining the readObject() methods of various classes which are available on the classpath of the vulnerable application an attacker can execute functions (including calling Runtime.exec() to execute local OS commands).

Can someone give a concrete Java example how can an **attacker** execute/inject local OS commands?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The [ysoserial](https://github.com/frohoff/ysoserial) project is a fully weaponized exploit kit that demonstrates how an attacker can execute OS commands.
It has [payloads for common vulnerable libraries](https://github.com/frohoff/ysoserial/tree/master/src/main/java/ysoserial/payloads) as well as [exploit implementations](https://github.com/frohoff/ysoserial/tree/master/src/main/java/ysoserial/exploit) for common software that uses java serialization.

An attacker just needs to identify a piece of software that has both a vulnerable class on its path, and performs deserialization on untrusted data.
Then all they need to do is send the payload into the deserializer and boom, the command is executed.

Comment: So Basically 'various classes which are available on the classpath' means that attacks on pure Java are out of the question, but when software uses freely available 3rd party libraries it becomes viable?

Comment: At least one version of java (jdk7u21) comes with a class that enables the attack. 
The common trend between each vulnerable class, is that its serializable, and allows you to execute an arbitrary class.
So long as you don't have a class like that in your project you are probably safe, best to just not use Java serialization anyway, not just because its insecure, but because its slow and produces bloated output.

Answer (score 2):

This tool exploits serialization bugs since 2013: https://github.com/joaomatosf/jexboss

Recently i tested it against many JSF applications sucessfully using "Mad gadget" (the tool generate mad-gadget/commons-collection payload automatically).

I followd the steps in this video: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=VaLSYzEWgVE